# Extract Web Data with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having issue with getting text of field from the web page using python 3 and bs4.  Code below.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd

    page = requests.get("https://www.mlssoccer.com/players")
    content = page.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

    data = soup.find('div', class_ = 'item-list' )

    names=[]

    for player in data:

         name = data.find_all('div', class_ = 'name')
         names.append(name)


    df= pd.DataFrame({'player':names})
```

the code works (ie executes) but I get the html tags in the output, rather than the text of the field (player name).  i tried:

```
    name = data.find_all('div', class_ = 'name').text
```

in the for loop but that doesn't work either.

Any pointers or references to help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get from the `find_all` is `ResultSet`, so yes you need to use `text` to retrieve name data you want but it won't work for a set. Therefore you need to use for loop to retrieve them one by one.

However, the text in `div` actually contains an `a` tag, so you need to further dig in it by `find('a')`.

```
for player in data:
    name = data.find_all('div', class_ = 'name')
    for obj in name:
        names.append(obj.find('a').text)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works great and solves my issue as expected

Answer (score 0):

you only need to loop once, use `.text` to get text inside element

```
....
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
data = soup.findAll('a', class_='name_link' )
names=[]
for player in data:
     names.append(player.text)
.....
```